# Best way to do async work in order to return fast response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm working on a REST API on ASP.NET. I want to know which is the best way to do a background work indepentently of sending the response to the client. Basically, I have a PUT method where I have to send several emails. Suppose they are 10 emails. I will resume all the methods to make everything more clear:

I tried the following and both ways the response was sent after the emails were sent and they took the same time:

Way 1:

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(string id, [FromBody]InformeModel informe)
    {
        if (CookieManager.ValidarCookie(Request.Headers.GetCookies("mb-session").FirstOrDefault()) == EstadoCookie.VALIDA)
        {
            await SendMails()

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }


    private async Task SendMails()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            foreach (string m in mails)
            {
                Mail mail = new Mail("test@test.com", 25, "test@test.com.ar", "myPass");
                mail.SendMailHTML(m, "Email Title", "This is the Email");
            }
        });
    }
```

Way 2:

```
    // PUT: api/Informes/5
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(string id, [FromBody]InformeModel informe)
    {
        if (CookieManager.ValidarCookie(Request.Headers.GetCookies("mb-session").FirstOrDefault()) == EstadoCookie.VALIDA)
        {
            SendMails()

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }


    private async void SendMails()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            foreach (string m in mails)
            {
                Mail mail = new Mail("test@test.com", 25, "test@test.com.ar", "myPass");
                mail.SendMailHTML(m, "Email Title", "This is the Email");
            }
        });
    }
```

Which is the best approach in order to send the response to the client and not have to wait that all emails have been sent?. Do I have to go with ThreadPool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go a step further with the decoupling and use a generic event, similar to a domain event.

If the controller can do its job and return a response whether or not the email has been sent, that strongly suggests that sending an email is way outside the responsibility of the controller. (With emails in particular, the controller can never know for sure whether an email has been sent anyway.)

In that scenario I'd use some sort of an event bus. Some examples use a static instance, or it could be something that you inject into the controller.

Then, instead of sending an email, the controller just raises an event, like

```
_eventBus.Raise(new SomethingHappenedEvent(argsThatIncludeRelevantInfo args));
```

Then you have an event handler (you could even have multiple) and an event handler sends the email, including making it `async` and handling any exceptions.

That makes unit testing much easier. You don't need to test whether your controller has sent an email. You can mock the event bus and just test that an event was raised. Then the event handlers can be tested separately.

[Here is an article on domain events](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) that was referenced a lot for a while. I'm sure that there's more up-to-date information out there.

A lot of information about these events is in the context of Domain Driven Development, but the principles and mechanics apply whether or not you're doing DDD. Your class becomes decoupled from other things that result from its methods, but which it itself shouldn't know or care about - like a controller that returns a response, and a side effect is sending an email.

[Here's an event bus implementation](https://github.com/scotthannen/Plasticfloor.EventBus) I did a while back. I don't think I included async handling, but that might make sense when you want to fire-and-forget. That's something I should revisit.

And as mentioned in a comment, fire-and-forget doesn't mean that the result of the event is trivial. To make sure that something happens it might make sense that the event handler puts a request in a queue instead of doing the work itself. That makes it more durable so you can make sure that whatever gets put in the queue gets processed.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I will take a look at the links you referred.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to wait for emails to be sent (or any related errors), you should do a "fire and forget". Solutions in order of robustness:

- Use [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/), robust fire-and-forget lib
- [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx) - will at least *try* to stop the app pool from killing of your emails in case of a recycle
- Unawaited Task.Run with continuation for error management:

Ex:

```
Task.Run(async () => await ..send emails.)
    .ContinueWith(t => logError(t.Exception.GetBaseException()),
                  TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I think I´ll go with Tash.Run without awaiting.

Comment: As others say on the subject; only go with unawaited Task.Run if you dont really mind if the task won't be executed. Which is quite rare, because if you don't really care, then why do it in the first place...

Comment: It is kind of a waste of a thread to run I/O bound work with Task.Run.

Comment: There are many legitimate use cases for fire and forget. One particularly applicable case is when the user has absolutely no ability to do anything whether the task succeeds or fails.

Comment: @theMayer if you are talking to me, I'm not arguing against fire and forget. I'm arguing against tying up a thread that is doing no work. I would use a distributed system like a message queue.

Comment: I really like Hangfire's implementation of batch oriented processing but I would strongly recommend against adding it to a "transactional" site. After significant growth on our production site, we ended up moving Hangfire to a dedicated site for batch processing because of it's resource consumption.

Comment: I'd favor using the QueueBackgroundWorkitem for true fire & forget. Handling exceptions on sending emails wouldn't be complete until they are actually send so I would delegate exception notification to the component doing the work to send them.

On thread usage, the ASP.NET threadpool manager keeps a separate pool of I/O Completion threads that would be needed in any case to perform sending the emails.

Comment: @theMayer No, not really. If work is truly fire and forget and you don't care if it succeeds or fails, then you wouldn't run it in the first place. We don't write code that does nothing.

Comment: @mason- fire and forget doesn't mean the system doesn't do something, but rather regards an interaction pattern with the system called "open feedback loop". You'd be surprised how often open feedback loops are encountered in the real world. Every time you send a text message, for example, there is no requirement on the other side to reply. Fire and forget in action. In software, every event notification is a fire-and-forget (or at least, should be).

Comment: @theMayer I didn't say the system didn't do something. What I said is that "fire and forget" is not a valid pattern. "Fire, and don't wait for the response right now" is a valid pattern. The "forget" part is what I'm taking issue with. If we didn't care whether our code worked or not, we wouldn't be running it in the first place. Yes, it's semantics, but devs deploy terrible "fire and forget" code because "well we can't do anything if it fails anyway" but then they have no idea of knowing if it ever works because they "forget".

Comment: @mason - I think you're taking the pattern too literally. But to your point, there are also legitimate cases where you just don't care. Your absolute statements are contrary to the myriad of situations that exist in the real world.

Comment: @theMayer I'm pointing out that the semantics are important here. There are no legitimate cases wheres where you don't care, otherwise you wouldn't write the code and execute the code in the first place. There does exist a lot of code in production that is truly "fire and forget" but that is absolutely a bad pattern to follow.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Not sure why I bother arguing for a solution that I don't really use myself, but to be meticulous - `Task.Run(async () => await ..send emails.)` won't tie up a thread (that was not what I wrote though, so I have edited my answer)